# Jwplayer how to separate between setup and events

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have a `display: none` div with the movie container. i want to show the div only after the user is clicking on some buttons.
On `$(document).ready` i set the player with `autostart': 'false'`.
is there after the user click on some buttons to show the container div, play the movie and use jwplayer events?

Comment: Do you have an example of where you tried this?